# How many planets have had their limbs scanned with radio signals?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, weather

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30355/12102) to *When did planetary scientists realize Venus' surface pressure was almost 100x that on Earth? How did they find out?* describes one example of scanning the limb of a planet using transmitted radio waves in order to study the atmosphere's properties.

JAXA's [Mars Tera-hertz Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera-hertz_Explorer) (TEREX) ([1](https://web.archive.org/web/20181125030853/https://www2.ccs.tsukuba.ac.jp/Astro/assets/doc/uchu-forum-2018-06-13-kasai.pdf), [2](https://www.soumu.go.jp/main_content/000462914.pdf)) plans to scan Mars's atmosphere for molecular emissions using a narrow, side-looking receive beam. (In this case there is no transmitter if I understand correctly, it's just recording emissions from the atmosphere)

[image: JAXA's Mars Tera-hertz Explorer TEREX]

But that's in the future.

Certainly Earth has had its limb scanned:

- [CICERO orbit design and optimization for GPS occultations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31949/12102)
- [Does NOAA still plan to deploy all twelve Cosmic-2 GPS radio occultation satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30154/12102)
- [Was SpaceX's launch of Formosat-5 more vertical than normal for any particular reason?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26211/12102)

**Question:** Besides Earth and Venus, have any other planets had their limbs scanned with radio signals?

Comment: [What does the phrase “limb of the earth” or “atmospheric limb” mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39347/what-does-the-phrase-limb-of-the-earth-or-atmospheric-limb-mean) "1. (astronomy) The apparent visual edge of a celestial body."

Comment: @Mazura thanks, the image included i the question also illustrates the distinction between scanning *the disk* of a body and scanning *its limb*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presentation contains a historical background of previous experiments.

http://iki.rssi.ru/seminar/2011070508/presentation/Gavrik.ppt

> О   модернизации наземных средств   и бортового   оборудования, используемых  в   радиофизических   экспериментах  перспективных космических  проектов. (ФИРЭ им. В.А. Котельникова РАН)

> On the modernization of ground-based facilities and on-board equipment used in radiophysical experiments in promising space projects.(Institute of Radio-engineering and Electronics by the Russian Academy of Science)

> выполнялось радиопросвечивание оболочек Луны, Марса, Венеры, Солнца, кометы Галлея
> [We] performed radio scanning of the [atmospheric] envelopes of the Moon, Mars, Venus, the Sun, Halley's comet

> Радиопросвечивание  ионосферы  и  атмосферы (традиционная методика экспериментов)

> Slide: Radio sensing of the ionosphere and atmosphere (traditional experimental technique) -

*The slide contains a list of missions in which experiments on radio scanning of the ionosphere and atmosphere were carried out:*

- 1971 Mars-2
- 1973 Luna-19
- 1974 Luna-22

  Mars-4

  Mars-5

  Mars-6
- 1975 Venera-9

Venera-10

- 1983 Venera-15

Venera-16

- 1989 Phobos-2

[image]